# FirebaseUI for android gives error on real device

Tags: android, firebase, google-signin, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Im using FirebaseUI for android for Google Sign-In. All is working fine on an emulator. But when I try to run the same app on my Galaxy S6 device, I get an error

```
unable to connect to service: com.google.firebase.auth.api.gms.service.START on com.google.android.gms
```

The version of Google Play Services installed on my phone is 9.0.83